# Solving Trigonometric Identities - Thinking questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

The question I have is a thinking question: If $\sin(x+y)=0.9$ and $\sin(x-y)=0.6$, determine $\sin x \cos y$. I am really not sure how to go about it.  Could I use the addition formula of sin and the subtraction formula of sin?

Comment: Yes indeed - using these formulas are the key to solving this. You should be able to see what to do to these two formulas in order to obtain the $\sin(x)\cos(y)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the addition formulas for sin, which are as follows;

$\sin(x+y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)+\sin(y)\cos(x)$

$\sin(x-y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)-\sin(y)\cos(x)$

You are given that $\sin(x+y)=0.9 $

so this implies  $\sin(x)\cos(y)+\sin(y)\cos(x)=0.9$

and you are also given $\sin(x-y)=0.6 $

which implies $\sin(x)\cos(y)-\sin(y)\cos(x)=0.6$

adding these equations, $2\sin(x)\cos(y)=1.5$

As in, $(\sin(x)\cos(y)-\sin(y)\cos(x))+(\sin(x)\cos(y)+\sin(y)\cos(x))=0.6+0.9$

$2\sin(x)\cos(y)=1.5$

dividing both sides by two will give the final answer
$\sin(x)\cos(y)=\frac{1.5}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

you know that $\sin(x)\cos(y) + \cos(x)\sin(y) = .9$ and $\sin(x)\cos(y) -\cos(x)\sin(y) = .6$ so if you add these two equations together you get $(\sin(x)\cos(y) + \cos(x)\sin(y)) + (\sin(x)\cos(y) -\cos(x)\sin(y)) = (.9) + (.6)$ which reduces to $2\sin(x)\cos(y) = 1.5$ and $\sin(x)\cos(y) = .75$